# How to systematically construct sigmoids having wobbly differentials?

Tags: calculus, analysis, soft-question, machine-learning, computational-mathematics

In machine learning using [neural networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network), [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) functions are often used to mimic the dynamics of biological neuron's plasticity. Often sigmoids with a smooth curve is desired, the properties strictly demanded on these functions are usually:

$$f(x+x_0) > f(x), \forall x \in \mathbb R\\\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x) = -1\\\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = 1$$

However as long as we have $f' = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \geq 0, \forall x\in \mathbb R$ this should still be fulfilled.

So assuming we have a pair $f, f'$ fulfilling the above constraints, are there any general methods we can apply to periodically (over $t$) "slow down" the learning,

---

**Own work**

So far, I have been thinking of, for example something like:

$${f_1}'(t) = (\sin(kx)^{2n}+\epsilon){f_1}'(t)\cdot$$

It is obvious to me that it will satisfy requirements above, maybe with some renormalization of the integral of $f'$ requrired. But in general it seems like a difficult modification because of the difficulty of doing analytic integration. Is there maybe some smarter modification we can do to a general $f$ or $f'$ which always gives an $f'$ for which $f$ is easy to calculate and always satisfies the conditions above?

Comment: what do you mean by "integrable"?

Comment: @marcotrevi : I mean that the integral is easy to express with elementary functions. That is of course not what the word means. I will edit.

Comment: but in machine learning you are anyway doing a lot of calculations. Why not integrate numerically also the sigmoid's derivative?

Comment: @marcotrevi : yes you are right, we might as well do that with a finite difference estimate or something like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without getting to differential equations, you could try with something like
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\sigma(k(wx+\sin(wx)))
\end{equation}
where $k,w$ are constants and $\sigma$ is your "non-wobbly" sigmoid.

I think there is no "correct" answer as the function you are searching for has a too broad definition...

Comment: Yes you are right. Interesting approach! I often add "soft-question" where I don't expect any single correct answer. It means that I am interested in many approaches and not any particular correct type of solution.